# How do I specify the destination bucket for an asset in AWS CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I'm reading the [AWS CDK Assets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_assets-readme.html) docs, and while it's possible to get the bucket's name with `s3BucketName`, it's not possible to specify such destination bucket explicitly when creating the asset.

I came across this [Github issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/659), which seems to suggest there's not way of specifying it at all. As for the reasons, it's unclear to me why this isn't possible. In that issue, IngussNeilands states: [*"Asset target is CDK deployment bucket, we should not be using that to store our lambda zip assets"*](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/659#issuecomment-762213227). What does this mean?

Comment: It means that you shouldn't care about the location of your assets. If you want to upload something to a specific bucket, then it's no longer an asset. In that case, use the `BucketDeployment` construct.

Comment: @smac2020 CDK does much more than provision CloudFormation resources. It also bundles and uploads your runtime assets for you (like docker images, and files)

Comment: Point being if you want to use this functionality in Lambda/Apps, etc, you typically use API.